# Displaying a message after specific attempts

Tags: php, session

I, am just learning PHP and as a project for myself I'm developing a small game wherein the user guesses the number from 1 to 100.
If he's correct, then it shows the same or else it shows the answer.
Now I have limited this to three tries and I want the user to see a message "Your 3 Tries are over" after the third try.
Along with a "Try again" button that destroys the session and allows him to restart the game. Please help me with the same.

Code is below:

```
<?php

$rand= rand(1,100);

$guess=$_POST['guess'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
session_start();

if(isset($submit)) {

if (!isset($_SESSION["attempts"])) $_SESSION["attempts"] = 0;

if ($_SESSION["attempts"] < 3) {

    if($guess<1 ||$guess>100) {
        echo "your guess must be a number between 1 and 100";
    }
    elseif($guess!=$rand)
    {
        echo "Incorrect,the correct answer is".$rand;
        $_SESSION["attempts"] = $_SESSION["attempts"] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "That is correct!";
    }
}

}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION["attempts"]);
    include_once('game.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: And what seems to be your problem? Didn't test the code, but it looks just fine.

Comment: I am not sure on how I display the message "Your 3 Tries are over" after the third try. Along with a "Try again" button that destroys the session and allows him to restart the game

Answer (score 1):

You made all that and don't know how to add 1 line?

```
if ($_SESSION["attempts"] < 3) {
    ...
} else {
    echo '3 tries are over, game over.';
    session_destroy();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dainis, It's just my 8th day with PHP. I am a web designer and a part time school teacher - I read about similar games online and decided to make one of my own that I may add to the school's website. I am sorry if you find me too ignorant.

Comment: I tried your method as well - however instead of just showing the "3 tries are over, game over." - It shows a message like "Incorrect,the correct answer is94 3 tries are over, game over." and allows the user to continue playing the game.

Comment: @user1595112 m8, do some work too, we just showed you the way, not wrote the entire code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not unset the session on each submit if there are a session. That way you can never count the tries as they are always reset by the unset.

Here is your code byt with the unset commented out and with the addition of an "3 tries" message.

> $guess=$_POST['guess']; $submit=$_POST['submit']; session_start();
>
> if(isset($submit)) { if (!isset($_SESSION["attempts"]))
>   $_SESSION["attempts"] = 0;
>
> if ($_SESSION["attempts"] < 3) {
>
> if($guess<1 ||$guess>100) { echo "your guess must be a number between
>   1 and 100";
>
> } elseif($guess!=$rand) { echo "Incorrect,the correct answer
>   is".$rand; $_SESSION["attempts"] = $_SESSION["attempts"] + 1;
>
> }
>
> else { echo "That is correct!";
>
> }
>
> } else {
>
> echo "Your 3 tries are up";
>
> }
>
> } else{
>
> //unset($_SESSION["attempts"]); include_once('game.php');
>
> }

Comment: Henkealg, thanks for the reply. It works perfectly. However, how do I add a "Try again" button along with "Your 3 tries are up" button.?

Comment: I figured it out. Added a a link to the previous file along with a "session_destroy()" Thanks.

Comment: @user1595112 good to hear that you got it working. Good luck with your  game. :)